# How to send json data using powershell from S3 to Neptune instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, turtle-rdf, amazon-neptune

I have a turtle file that I wish to send from S3 server to the Neptune instance on powershell. Below is the command I am using

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://edwardspoc.civwhymjvz19.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182 -ContentType application/json  -body '
{ 
  "source" : "s3://cedwardsneptune/ATC.ttl", 
  "format" : "turtle",  
  "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:s3:::cedwardsneptune", 
  "region" : "us-east-1", 
  "failOnError" : "FALSE",
  "parserConfiguration" : {
  "namedGraphUri" : "http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/ATC"
  }
}'
```

This is giving me the following error

> Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

I made subtle changes but nothing seems to be working.  Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like answered as part of this post?

Comment: no.. i marked the answer correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you having says that you are trying to send a BODY when your REQUEST VERB does not allow it.

Basically you are doing GET and trying to send a body. When GET verb is not allowed to send a body part. 
Probably you need to use POST method (check specific webservice documentation)

For that I recommend you next format:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential (If you could have)
$Url = "http://edwardspoc.civwhymjvz19.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182"
$Body = '{ 
 "source" : "s3://cedwardsneptune/ATC.ttl", 
  "format" : "turtle",  
  "iamRoleArn" : "arn:aws:s3:::cedwardsneptune", 
  "region" : "us-east-1", 
  "failOnError" : "FALSE",
  "parserConfiguration" : {
  "namedGraphUri" : "http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/ATC"
  }
}'



Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -ContentType $contentType -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -OutFile output.csv
```

(*)Of course -OutFile is optional

And about JSON There is a cmdlet called ConvertFrom-JSON you can use commonly when you need to parse an output(that is a JSON).

p.e:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $url -Credential $Cred -Body $body | 
ConvertFrom-JSON | Select field1, field2, field3
```

If you expect an output (json) having field1, field2, field3 as fields

Comment: it is giving me error for $contentType variable ...    i think application/json should be in quotes (as a string) ....    but when I did that it is giving a new error   $body cannot be parsed :(

Comment: Yes, My json missed a '}' from "parserConfiguration". I ve edited my answer, give a look

Comment: Heyy @Sam It is throwing me an error that cannot validate credentials for iamRole. I do have access_key and secret_key ...  how should i pass it in creds  . I searched on amazondocs but not helpful :|

Comment: Check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html#specifying-your-aws-credentials-use

Comment: You have to add the role to your cluster first. Have tried the full section on bulk loading data from the docs? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-IAM.html#bulk-load-tutorial-IAM-add-role-cluster